# Insert at the beginning of a file with Node.js

Tags: node.js, filesystems

Is there way to append to the beginning of a file in node (maybe to insert).  I was looking around her http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html but didn't see anything, I know that append brings adds to the end of the file, but is there a way to add to the beginning of a file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no built in way to insert at the beginning of the file in nodejs.

This is nothing specific to nodejs, it's the same way in [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844273/is-it-possible-to-prepend-data-to-an-file-without-rewriting) [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343044/c-prepending-to-beginning-of-a-file) [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537944/prepend-lines-to-file-in-java) [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454298/prepend-a-line-to-an-existing-file-in-python) and pretty much any other languages I know and is just how the file system works. ( [here is why not by the way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/01/10097859.aspx))

You can however, read the file with `fs.readFile` and then write it back with the stuff you need added.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the "unix" way with `shelljs` and pipes.

```
const shell = require('shelljs')
shell
  .echo('This line will be on top\n')
  .cat('originalFile.txt')
  .to('originalFile.txt')
```